# Azure DevOps Server 2019 Build queued but not started

Tags: azure-devops, hyper-v

I have an OnPremise Azure DevOps Server 2019.

I have installed two agents on a Hyper-V machine (Interactive and Service, v2.144.2, 64 bit, Windows 10 v10.0.17763).

After a build has been executed, the machines are reset. The agents are displayed as Online and Idle. When I then try to start a build, it is displayed in the queue, but the build is not started. It's the same when I want to start a release pipeline on the machine.

The service agent can run builds after the reset.

I have restarted the machine several times after the reset.
I also updated the agents using the REST API.

What do I have to do so that the builds can run again on my reset machine?

[image]

There is one Warning in my _diag logfile:

[2019-11-12 11:05:21Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Authentication failed with status code 401.
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2019 11:05:20 GMT
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer, Basic realm="https://*****/", Negotiate, NTLM
x-tfs-processid: 55397bf1-233e-4c18-aa64-a9b5739f1834
activityid: 09185372-bb67-4722-858c-cd190901e510
x-tfs-session: f2682dfa-5de9-4680-bd2b-69399f3de32d
x-vss-e2eid: 29fcc2fb-f3b6-4834-b01c-bef40bf18c06
x-tfs-soapexception: %3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%3Csoap%3AEnvelope%20xmlns%3Asoap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F05%2Fsoap-envelope%22%3E%3Csoap%3ABody%3E%3Csoap%3AFault%3E%3Csoap%3ACode%3E%3Csoap%3AValue%3Esoap%3AReceiver%3C%2Fsoap%3AValue%3E%3Csoap%3ASubcode%3E%3Csoap%3AValue%3EUnauthorizedRequestException%3C%2Fsoap%3AValue%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3ASubcode%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3ACode%3E%3Csoap%3AReason%3E%3Csoap%3AText%20xml%3Alang%3D%22en%22%3ETF400813%3A%20Resource%20not%20available%20for%20anonymous%20access.%20Client%20authentication%20required.%3C%2Fsoap%3AText%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3AReason%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3AFault%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3ABody%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3AEnvelope%3E
x-tfs-serviceerror: TF400813%3A%20Resource%20not%20available%20for%20anonymous%20access.%20Client%20authentication%20required.
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
lfs-authenticate: NTLM
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Edit 1: I posted the issue also in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/811079/azure-devops-server-2019-build-queued-but-not-star.html)

Edit 2: Added diag-log

Comment: Could you please share the agent _diag log to check if there is any error or warning message? By the way, there is a similar issue about build pipeline, you can check if it can fix your issue. Here is the link.https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/576411/tfs-builds-not-starting.html

Comment: @FrankWang-MSFT: I have added the warning log entry. I had already seen the post you linked, but unfortunately it doesn't help with my problem.

Comment: Suggest you deploying a new agent which using the default `Network Service` account or a PAT, then try it again. To generate a PAT, you can refer to this link for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts

Comment: We have already registered the agent with a PAT.

Comment: Did you have redeploy a new agent in you reset machine? According to your comment, I don't find if you have redeployed a new agent on the reset machine. Did you get the same error after you redeployed it?